# Full refresh of website's content on iPad orientation change

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad

I am doing a website with Foundation 4.
I want to do refresh totally the webpage's contents when user goes from portrait to        landscape.
I've tried to use this code:

```
window.onorientationchange = function()
{
    window.location.reload();
}
```

but it doesn't change totally my website's content

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
window.onresize = function(){
     window.location.reload();
}
```

it works for me.